# How to hide relationships column in Eloquent?

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I have the Eloquent query in which three tables are connected.

```
      $result = Kompaniya::with(['Otdel'=>function($query){
            $query->select('kompaniya_id','title as otdel','id');
            $query->with(array('polzovatel'=>function($query){
                    $query->select('otdel_id',DB::raw("CONCAT(fam, ' ', imya, ' ', otchestvo) AS full_name"));
                }));
        }])
            ->get(['title as kompaniya','id']);
```

because I use function WITH, so have to select ID. But in result it is needlessly.It looks like a tree. So how I can hide unnecessary fields?
View of result:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "kompaniya": "Pfeffer-White",
            "otdel": [
                {
                    "kompaniya_id": 1,
                    "otdel": "Securities Sales Agent",
                    "id": 7,
```

but the result should be:

```
 "data": [
        {
            "kompaniya": "Pfeffer-White",
            "otdel": [
                {
                    "otdel": "Securities Sales Agent",
```

without kompaniya_id and id

So how I cat hide these fields, without $hidden in Model, may be using makeHidden?

Comment: In the `Department` class, set  the attribute `protected $hidden = ['id','company_id'];`

Comment: Are you returning a JSON response?

Comment: @IlGala yes, i am

Comment: Then you should use the [Api resources](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources) I'll add a detailed answer

Comment: @N69S but if in another query i need in these fields

Comment: @IlGala Yeah, thank you. I know about it, but  I need in simpler solution

Comment: there are only those two (non messy) solutions and @IlGala's suits your need best

Comment: @N69S Can not i to use makeHidden in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, since you're returning a JSON response, the best solution in my opinion is to use the [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources)

> When building an API, you may need a transformation layer that sits between your Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually returned to your application's users. Laravel's resource classes allow you to expressively and easily transform your models and model collections into JSON.

In this way you can create different type of responses depending on your needs. Here is an example:

```php
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        // Since the $request object is passed as input, you can check
        // parameters, route names, and so on. This example uses the route name

        $default = [
          'name' => $this->name,
          'email' => $this->email
        ];

        if($request->routeIs('profile')) {
          $default['profile'] = new ProfileResource($this->whenLoaded('profile'));
        } else if($request->routeIs('orders')) {
          $default['accountNumber'] = $this->account_number;
          $default['orders'] = new OrdersCollection($this->whenLoaded('orders'));
          $default['invoices'] = new InvoicesCollection($this->whenLoaded('invoices'));
        }

        return $default;
    }
}
```

In this way you can have multiple requests and json responses with a single resource model depending on the request and show / hide fields without changing your model default behaviour.

Another approach may be creating a resource for each request but, in my opinion, this will break the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: If you write that  a lot of resource will break DRY Principle. How many resources I can create for one Model?

Comment: How many you want... I prefer to create a single resource and multiple private / protected methods that returns the formatted resource depending on the request route or attributes or whatever